# How to generate sha256 hashes of hexadecimal binary data in c++?

Tags: c++, openssl, sha, xxd

I need a function in C++ that generate similar result what this command generate in linux.

> echo -n "616161616161616" | xxd -r -p | sha256sum -b | awk '{print
>   $1}'

What this command does is: given an hexadump, convert it to binary file format, and display the sha256 hash of the binary file.xxd -r converts the hexadump to binary file

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Can't you just `git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/coreutils` and use the routines from sha256sum?

Comment: `std::string f() { return "e46240714b5db3a23eee60479a623efba4d633d27fe4f03c904b9e219a7fbe60"; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should know that your command-line version is missing a nibble. I.e., if you send `'616161616161616`'` through xxd -r -p, then back through xxd, you'll see this:

```
echo -n "616161616161616" | xxd -r -p | xxd
00000000: 6161 6161 6161 61                        aaaaaaa
```

Note the last nibble `6` is missing. The xxd utility consumes hex in *pairs* of digits. Once there are no more *pairs* it stops and emits the final output. Chances are you were *expecting* behavior that treated the *leading* nibble as a single octet, and therefore something like this:

```
echo -n "0616161616161616" | xxd -r -p | xxd
00000000: 0616 1616 1616 1616                      ........
```

In either case, and however you want to handle that, you should nonetheless be made aware of the issue.

Regarding your actual problem, the OpenSSL library has a fairly rich set of features that let you do most of what you're asking near-trivially. Calculating the digest from the input string is fairly simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>

int main()
{
    std::string strHex = "616161616161616"; // get this from wherever

    // prepend zero-nibble for odd character counts.
    if (strHex.length() % 2)
        strHex.insert(strHex.begin(), '0');

    // convert to blob. returns dynamic memory allocated with
    //  OPENSSL_malloc. Use OPENSSL_free to destroy it.
    long len = 0;
    unsigned char *bin = OPENSSL_hexstr2buf(strHex.c_str(), &len);

    // digest the blob
    const EVP_MD *md_algo = EVP_sha256();
    unsigned int md_len = EVP_MD_size(md_algo);
    std::vector<unsigned char> md( md_len );
    EVP_Digest(bin, len, md.data(), &md_len, md_algo, nullptr);

    // free the input data.
    OPENSSL_free(bin);

    // print the buffer to stdout in hex.
    char *hexOut = OPENSSL_buf2hexstr(md.data(), md_len);
    std::cout << hexOut << '\n';
    OPENSSL_free(hexOut);

    return 0;
}
```

Note the above code takes the approach of prepending a zero-nibble in the case of an odd input length. If that isn't the behavior you want (i.e. if you want the exact same ignore-the-trailing-odd-nibble behavior as your question text), the alternative is to trim the last nibble off (which I seriously doubt is what you want is it removes relevant bits and is a recipe for digest collisions, but your call).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>

int main()
{
    std::string strHex = "616161616161616"; // get this from wherever

    // prepend zero-nibble for odd character counts.
    if (strHex.length() % 2)
        strHex.pop_back();

    // convert to blob. returns dynamic memory allocated with
    //  OPENSSL_malloc. Use OPENSSL_free to destroy it.
    long len = 0;
    unsigned char *bin = OPENSSL_hexstr2buf(strHex.c_str(), &len);

    // digest the blob
    const EVP_MD *md_algo = EVP_sha256();
    unsigned int md_len = EVP_MD_size(md_algo);
    std::vector<unsigned char> md( md_len );
    EVP_Digest(bin, len, md.data(), &md_len, md_algo, nullptr);

    // free the input data.
    OPENSSL_free(bin);

    // print the buffer to stdout in hex.
    char *hexOut = OPENSSL_buf2hexstr(md.data(), md_len);
    std::cout << hexOut << '\n';
    OPENSSL_free(hexOut);

    return 0;
}
```

In *both* cases above, the resulting output is preconfigured as colon-separated octets. I.e. the latter example output looks like this:

```
E4:62:40:71:4B:5D:B3:A2:3E:EE:60:47:9A:62:3E:FB:A4:D6:33:D2:7F:E4:F0:3C:90:4B:9E:21:9A:7F:BE:60
```

This is due to the rather-limited feature capability of `OPENSSL_buf2hexstr`. If this isn't what you want (probably isn't), you could always manually print it yourself using a simple lookup table, processing each octet as two nibbles:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>

int main()
{
    std::string strHex = "616161616161616";

    // prepend zero-nibble for odd character counts.
    if (strHex.length() % 2)
        strHex.pop_back();

    // convert to blob. returns dynamic memory allocated with
    //  OPENSSL_malloc. Use OPENSSL_free to destroy it.
    long len = 0;
    unsigned char *bin = OPENSSL_hexstr2buf(strHex.c_str(), &len);

    // digest the blob
    const EVP_MD *md_algo = EVP_sha256();
    unsigned int md_len = EVP_MD_size(md_algo);
    std::vector<unsigned char> md( md_len );
    EVP_Digest(bin, len, md.data(), &md_len, md_algo, nullptr);

    // free the input data.
    OPENSSL_free(bin);

    // dump as continuous hex string
    static const char alpha[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    for (auto c : md)
    {
        std::cout << alpha[ (c >> 4) & 0xF];
        std::cout << alpha[ c & 0xF];
    }
    std::cout.put('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
e46240714b5db3a23eee60479a623efba4d633d27fe4f03c904b9e219a7fbe60
```

Anyway, longer than I intended, but hope it was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The actual algorithm depends on what you want to do - you could convert the hexadecimal to a string. I did that in the examples below.

What you would first have to do is convert the string to binary, which can be done with:

```
std::string toBin(std::string str){
    int s = str.length();
    std::string bin = ""
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        int v = int(s[i]);
        while (val > 0){
            (val % 2)? bin.push_back('1') : bin.push_back('0');
            val /= 2;
        }
    }
    std::reverse(bin.begin(), bin.end());
}
```

However, the next part of the code is so long that I sadly cannot include it in this answer. But I will link you to a website which contains (hopefully) all the code you need. http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-sha256-function

Best wishes.